# ionic 4 AngularFireAuthGuard issue - not working as described on github

Tags: angular, ionic4, angularfire

I am using typescript with angularjs 8 along with the ionic 4 platform. The angularfireguard https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md method to block unauthorized access to routes, works fine on the localhost when I change the code from '=>' to '='
that is from

```
const redirectUnauthorizedToLanding = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['auth/login']);
                     to the below code:

const redirectUnauthorizedToLanding = redirectUnauthorizedTo(['auth/login']);
```

However it fails to prevent unauthorized users accessing pages meant for authorized personnel , This happens when its deployed on google Firebase cloud host not on the localhost. Could anyone clarify why this is the case?, any help will be highly appreciated.

**My Code from app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { AngularFireAuthGuard, loggedIn, redirectLoggedInTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
    import { redirectUnauthorizedTo, canActivate } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

    const redirectUnauthorizedToLanding = redirectUnauthorizedTo(['auth/login']);

    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/walkthrough', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'walkthrough', loadChildren: () => import('./walkthrough/walkthrough.module').then(m => m.WalkthroughPageModule) },
      { path: 'getting-started', loadChildren: () => import('./getting-started/getting-started.module').then(m => m.GettingStartedPageModule) },
      { path: 'auth/login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginPageModule) },
      { path: 'auth/signup', loadChildren: () => import('./signup/signup.module').then(m => m.SignupPageModule) },
      // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
      { path: 'auth/forgot-password', loadChildren: () => import('./forgot-password/forgot-password.module').then(m => m.ForgotPasswordPageModule) },
      {
        path: 'app',
        loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule),
        ...canActivate(redirectUnauthorizedToLanding)
      },
      {
        path: 'contact-card',
        loadChildren: () => import('./contact-card/contact-card.module').then(m => m.ContactCardPageModule),
        ...canActivate(redirectUnauthorizedToLanding)
      },
```

**My Ionic info output:**

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.10 (/home/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.802.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.2.1
   @angular/cli                  : 8.2.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.1.1
   @capacitor/core : 1.1.1

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.17.0 (/home/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.11.3
   OS     : Linux 5.3
```

Comment: FYI for anyone else having this problem this is also [an open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2247)

Answer (score 0):

The solution, I found works fine even on production deployment and development version too.

All you need to do is change the parameters in the routes from

```
...canActivate(redirectUnauthorizedToLanding)
```

to the below:

```
canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: {authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLanding }
```

In the routes, change all the route parameters to the above given code line as shown in the example below:

```
{
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule),
    canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: {authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLanding }
  },
```

This worked for me while deploying on firebase hosting.